# Jquery to Get attribute values of dom elements matching a class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a series of html elements such as

```
<li id="1" class="jstree-unchecked jstree-open">
<li id="2" class="jstree-checked jstree-open">
<li id="3" class="jstree-unchecked jstree-open">
<li id="4" class="jstree-checked jstree-open">
<li id="5" class="jstree-checked jstree-open">
<li id="6" class="jstree-unchecked jstree-open">
<li id="7" class="jstree-undetermined jstree-open">
```

I want the id's of the elements that have the classname {*jstree-checked* or *jstree-undetermined*}.

I have tried using selectors, but is there a linq way in JQuery?

Could you please help what the jQuery would look like? The list of id's can be comma separated.

The output: "2,4,5,7"

Comment: Or you could spend at most an hour reading through [the jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com) and then going forward know how to do this yourself, instantly.

Comment: Side note: Although `id` values starting with digits are [valid in HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute), they [didn't used to be](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name) and still are [not valid in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) and so (as jQuery uses CSS selectors) it's usually best to avoid them.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I think OP isn't actually using these values in his code and just wanted 'sample values' to demonstrate. I sure hope that at least. There is no point assigning arbitrarily named IDs to elements. More than that, assigning sequential IDs to elements is usually indicative of a much greater problem. If any of you reading this is doing this sort of thing, consider your code's structure. T.J. Still, solid comment.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Regarding your latter comment, I had a mistake in a selector at first, but corrected, as certainly it should be `OR` and not `and`.

Comment: I have corrected the question.

Comment: @VisioN: Perfectly understandable mistake (if we can even call it that), you answered the text and then revised when you realized the text was in error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method:

```
var ids = $(".jstree-checked, .jstree-undetermined").map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();

console.log(ids.join());  // "2,4,5,7"
```

Comment: Seems unfair that the poor quality of the question seems to be preventing people upvoting the good answer, +1.

Comment: Very nice and appropriate use of `.map`. The only thing I'd change is calling `.get()` first and using native `.map` but this solution is more cross browser complaint.

Comment: @T.J. poor quality of the question? How else would you keep the question simple..?

Comment: @jaxxbo: Simple questions are good, but a _better_ question would go on to say "I've tried the following: [insert some code here] but it didn't work." That is, a good question for Stack Overflow demonstrates some effort at having solved the problem, rather than stating a general requirement and asking others to solve the whole thing. VisioN: +1.